# NextJS, fetch, multipart/form-data, missing boundary

Tags: next.js, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data, boundary

I've faced with issue while proxy http request with multipart form data by NextJS. I have to send file from a client fide to next js, after that - to FastApi service.

The problem was:

```
 fetch("https://127.0.0.1:3000/api/newfile", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
   body: new FormData(form)
 });
```

> headers request: "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"

In order for NextJS API to parse the file, you need a header with boundary

Something like this:

> multipart/form-data; boundary=----< generate boundary >

For a long time I could not figure out how to get it.
There is an exit. It is necessary not to fill in "Content-Type".
And then the browser itself will generate this header by passing the form-data.

For example:

```
fetch("https://127.0.0.1:3000/api/newfile", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {},
   body: new FormData(form)
 });
```

I also noticed that the problem concerns fetch

When I used XMLHttpRequest I didn't face such problem.

Further, the header can easily be passed further to FastAPI

in API:

```
req.headers["content-type"]
```

Comment: What is the question?